# What would be the best way to write a query to produce a table given the following data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, row-number

I have a table that contains the following data:

```
  ADD_Col         Data      OrderId     Output     NEW_ADD        Col1       Col2
  -----          ------   -------      ----->       -------     --------   -------
     AD*A*1      A       96                           A           1          2
     AD*A*1      B       95                           B           1          1
     AD*A*1      C       94                           C           0.8        1
     AD*A*1      D       93                           D           5          2
     AD*A*2      1       92 
     AD*A*2      1       91
     AD*A*2      0.8     90
     AD*A*2      5       89
     AD*A*3      2       88
     AD*A*3      1       87
     AD*A*3      1       86
     AD*A*3      2       85
```

This data is all in the same table and I need to link each letter to each factor. I was thinking of doing a `ROW_NUMBER()` and joining based on the respective row number and assign my letter the same number either that or `DENSERANK`. What would be the best way to achieve this? If you can please provide query examples that would be great thanks.

Comment: What defines the order of your data? I see nothing that can retain that order using an `ORDER BY`; making what you are asking impossible.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct the other column I have at my disposal is order Id. Adding to example.

Comment: I highly recommend not using reserved keywords for column names.

Comment: This was just an example and is not used in my code. I have changed this in my example provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you need to do is normalise your data here. Here I use `PARSENAME` to get the "column Number", and then `ROW_NUMBER` to number the relevant rows in the groups. Finally I use a Cross tab to Pivot to data:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT V.[Key],
           V.data,
           V.[Order],
           PARSENAME(REPLACE(V.[Key],'*','.'),1) AS ColNo,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V.[Key] ORDER BY V.[Order] DESC) AS RN
    FROM (VALUES('AD*A*1','A',96),       
                ('AD*A*1','B',95),       
                ('AD*A*1','C',94),       
                ('AD*A*1','D',93),       
                ('AD*A*2','1',92),
                ('AD*A*2','1',91),
                ('AD*A*2','0.8',90),
                ('AD*A*2','5',89),
                ('AD*A*3','2',88),
                ('AD*A*3','1',87),
                ('AD*A*3','1',86),
                ('AD*A*3','2',85))V([Key],[data],[Order]))
SELECT MAX(CASE C.ColNo WHEN '1' THEN C.[data] END) AS New_ADD,
       MAX(CASE C.ColNo WHEN '2' THEN C.[data] END) AS Col1,
       MAX(CASE C.ColNo WHEN '3' THEN C.[data] END) AS Col2
FROM CTE C
GROUP BY C.RN;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Larnu I am digesting this as we speak. This is what i need, but let me ask you something. What would your approach be if we did not have the column numbers? Also, going back to what you said before about missing order, why would it be impossible to accomplish this task without an order column? Still learning the ropes for SQL so I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Because if you have nothing to order by, how to you now that the value `5` is related to `D`? Without a column to determine that, there's no way you could "marry" them up, @ErickRamirez .

Comment: The number is arbitary, @ErickRamirez . it could be a letter, for example; it's just a value to identify which column it belongs in.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.Data "Key"
       , t2.Data "Col1"
       , t3.Data "Col2" 
from ((SELECT Data, 
              row_number() over (order by Key_C) rn
       from my_table 
       where Key_C = 'AD*A*1') t1
       left join
      (SELECT Data,
              row_number() over (order by Key_C) rn
       from my_table
       where Key_C = 'AD*A*2') t2
       on t1.rn = t2.rn
       left join
      (SELECT Data,
              row_number() over (order by Key_C) rn
       from my_table
       where Key_C = 'AD*A*3') t3
       on t2.rn = t3.rn);
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2458ef0f3ef2a115448dde11e072de3e)

Comment: 3 scans of `my_table` seems like a little overkill here.

Answer (score 1):

For your sample data this will work:

```
with cte as (
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by [key] order by [OrderId desc]) rn,
    dense_rank() over (order by [key]) rk
  from tablename
)  
select t1.data, 
  max(case when t2.rk = 2 then t2.data end) col1,
  max(case when t2.rk = 3 then t2.data end) col2
from (select * from cte where rk = 1) t1
inner join (select * from cte where rk in (2, 3)) t2
on t2.rn = t1.rn
group by t1.data
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9ece15ca50bad11ef9ddbdf6d1d8bda6).
Results:

```
> data | col1 | col2
> :--- | :--- | :---
> A    | 1    | 2   
> B    | 1    | 1   
> C    | 0.8  | 1   
> D    | 5    | 2
```

Comment: I like this answer because it accomplishes the task and is easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #RawData
SELECT 
    [ADD_Col]
    ,[Data]
    ,[OrderId]
    ,REPLACE([ADD_Col], 'AD*A*', '') AS [Level]
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [ADD_Col] ORDER BY [OrderId] DESC) AS [Grouping]
INTO
    #RawData
FROM 
    [SourceTable]

SELECT
    rd.[Data]
    ,rdc1.[Data] AS [Col1]
    ,rdc2.[Data] AS [Col2]
FROM
    #RawData AS rd
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #RawData AS rdc1
        ON rdc1.[Level] = 2
        AND rd.[Grouping] = rdc1.[Grouping]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #RawData AS rdc2
        ON rdc2.[Level] = 3
        AND rd.[Grouping] = rdc2.[Grouping]
WHERE
    rd.[Level] = 1
```